# MySql count table values from comma separated

Tags: mysql

my table looks like this

[my_table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c7WC.png)

I need the result to be like

[expected_result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DtB5.png)

noting that sometimes I have in my table value then "," then another value, and sometimes value then "," then space then value, and some empty values

Comment: Your table does not look like a picture, and if your result should look like a picture, than the tag is wrong, it should not be `mysql`, but something like `imageprocessing` (if that tag does exist)...

Comment: You should probably check the design of your table. I advise you to save the multi-values record into multiple records instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will involve a sequence of steps.

Assuming your records are as in table1 -

`+-------------------------------+
| title                         |
+-------------------------------+
| sales,marketing,operations    |
| sales                         |
| operations,project management |
| sales,operations              |
|                               |
| ,                             |
+-------------------------------+`

Step 1 : Create temporary table -

`create temporary table temp( val char(255) );`

Step 2 : Create sql statement dynamically
`set @sql=concat("insert into temp (val) values ('", replace(( select group_concat(title) as t from table1), ",", "'),('"),"');");`

Step 3 : Prepare SQL statement
`prepare stmt1 from @sql;`

Step 4 : Execute the SQL statement created above
`execute stmt1;`

Step 5 : Run below SQL to have required output -
`select val, count(val) from temp group by val having val!=""`

Output - 
`+--------------------+------------+
| val                | count(val) |
+--------------------+------------+
| marketing          |          1 |
| operations         |          3 |
| project management |          1 |
| sales              |          3 |
+--------------------+------------+`

Comment: thanks a lot for the response, I have tried this but I got access error, I assume that I dont have creating tables access. I was trying to do so through "flatten table" but dont have enough experience doing so

Comment: How big is your table data ? (number of records)

Comment: my table is 14 columns and 1.5 million rows

Answer (score 0):

Another Answer -

If you have limited values for title's try using below sql for each title's.

`SELECT 'sales', SUM(ROUND((LENGTH(title)- LENGTH(REPLACE(title, "sales", "")) ) / LENGTH("sales"))) AS`count`FROM table1;`

Output - 

`+-------+-------+
| sales | count |
+-------+-------+
| sales |     3 |
+-------+-------+`

Obviously this will hit performance but saves from table creation privileges.

Answer (score 0):

With the following select you get all the values in the coma seperated Column in their own rows and you can use ot to do anything you want. this runs also on mysql 5.x Versions.

If your have more than 6 Words in your column you have to expand the rifgt sight if the inner join

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) title
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(title, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(title)-n.digit;
```

Gives you

```
title
sales
sales
operations
sales
marketing
project management
operations
operations
```

And with

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1) title, Count(*)
FROM
  table1
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT 0 digit UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3  UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6) n
  ON LENGTH(REPLACE(title, ',' , '')) <= LENGTH(title)-n.digit
  GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(title, ',', n.digit+1), ',', -1);
```

You get

```
title               Count(*)
sales               3
operations          3
marketing           1
project management  1
```

dbfiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a3f5dc5f7b31f0270d595d2635a99a08